# What kind of piano exercise books has notes and chords mixed together?

Tags: piano, fingering, exercises

I have seen piano exercises with only notes, with their fingerings, like Hanon.

And I have seen piano exercises with only chords, and their fingerings.

I was wondering if there are any books containing exercises with notes and chords mixed together, like in a real song, with fingerings underneath as guide of course.

Would love any suggestions

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for would be very useful so I doubt they exist.

Comment: Did you google for what you're asking here and looking up under: images? There are lots of easy piano arrangements with chord names and fingerings. e.g. Sikorski or musescore ...

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli In general, it's best to avoid asking users to google stuff. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/247309  and   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/247309

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Schumann's Album für die Jugend?  They are not exercises as such, but are multiple short pieces written for educational purposes.  There are plenty of pieces in there that combine melody with chords.  The edition that I have includes fingering suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about what kind of exercises you want, because you mix *Hanon* and *real songs* into the same questions. Most classical piano methods don't contain songs, but little dance-like or short two-part pieces.

Anyway, things like

- https://imslp.org/wiki/Vorschule_im_Klavierspiel%2C_Op.101_(Beyer%2C_Ferdinand)
- https://imslp.org/wiki/100_Progressive_Studies%2C_Op.139_(Czerny%2C_Carl)
- https://imslp.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_compl%C3%A8te_et_progressive_de_piano_(Bertini%2C_Henri)

...will give you lots of material mixing scales, chords, arpeggios, broken chords, etc.

At imslp.org try search for words like "method, study, etude, etc" combined with "easy, beginner, facile, etc."

You can also look for folk dance type material: 
  - [https://imslp.org/wiki/120_Country_Dances,_Jigs,_Reels,_Hornpipes,*etc.*(Westrop,_Thomas)](https://imslp.org/wiki/120_Country_Dances,_Jigs,_Reels,_Hornpipes,_etc._(Westrop,_Thomas))
  - https://imslp.org/wiki/Harding's_All-Round_Collection_of_Jigs%2C_Reels_and_Country_Dances_(Various)